# Automate AWS Quicksight Athena datasource creation with AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a datasource of type ATHENA in Quicksight using python aws sdk, but I get this error:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateDataSource operation: ATHENA source doesn't support CredentialPair authentication.

Here is my code:

```
ds = qs.create_data_source(
    AwsAccountId=aws_account_id,
    DataSourceId=datasource_id,
    Name=datasource_name,
    Type="ATHENA",
    DataSourceParameters={
        "AthenaParameters": {
            "WorkGroup": workgroup
        }
    },
    Credentials={
        "CredentialPair": {
            "Username": username,
            "Password": password,
            "AlternateDataSourceParameters": [
                {
                    "AthenaParameters": {
                        "WorkGroup": workgroup
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

    }
)
```

As per the [create_data_source documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_data_source), "*Currently, only credentials based on user name and password are supported.*", and ATHENA is supposed to be supported.

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: have you tried removing the "AlternateDataSourceParameters" from the CredentialPair?  I don't think you need that there since you already have it in DataSourceParameters

Comment: Facing same issue.